# Image border line appearing with all correct CSS settings

Tags: html, css

I am facing a strange issue. In my code, I have stacked 4 images with margin, padding set to 0 and display set to block. But, still, a line appears between two images. While checking, I found that the borderline disappears when I move to other tab and come back. Is this a chrome error or what? I have also tried line-height:0.

Comment: Could you share the html and CSS? Also check  if  there  is some css on image focus or something?

Comment: Can you explain the problem with a picture or code?

Comment: you can see the issue live at http://eyaas.in.... Here on the home page there are 4 images with a borderline between them. This gap disappears if you move to another tab on desktop. On mobile everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

The `bug` is not only occuring by switching tabs, but also you can't see what happens to your website when you switch to some other tab.

If you `perform action outside of the window and click back again inside the window`. You will see that the space removed between images as an animation.

[image]

---

## Reason of this bug

One thing that I found on your site is that this `bug` is occuring because of your `scripting`.

I recorded loading performance of your website and found that this animation has occured because of your scripting and rendering. As you can see the Red boxes are highlighting it.

[image]

The track that is in the red box showing when the space is removed between `images`